# Como apagar equipos de una OU en el AD sin GPO (intente shutdown -i)

Tags: windows10, powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server, directorioactivo

Como apagar equipos de una OU en el AD sin GPO (intente shutdown -i, pero solo me deja agregar equipo por equipo, no me deja tomar un grupo de equipos)

se que podria haber forma con la GPo, pero el caso es que trato de forzar el apagado justamente porque los usuarios no reinician sus equipos para que aplique una GPO, asi que no le veo mucha logica a crear otra GPo para que aplique una GPO.  .-.

les agradezco su aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es obtener todos los servidores que pertenecen a una OU en particular. Para ello se debe utilizar el cmdlet **Get-ADComputer**, filtrando con una query específica:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Sistemas, DC=dominio, DC=local"
```

Donde para el ejemplo se uso el dominio *dominio.local* y la OU *Sistemas*.

El siguiente punto es utilizar el cmdlet **Stop-Computer** para realizar el shutdown en cada servidor. Utilizamos la función **foreach** para ello:

```
Foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Stop-Computer –computer $server
}
```

Comment: Gracias! o/ , muchas gracias!